# Why does Communist propaganda portray capitalists as wearing Ultra-Orthodox (Haredi) Jewish male uniforms?

Tags: communism, propaganda, antisemitism

Black hat, black suit, black pants, white shirt.

[image]

Comment: The correct question would be "why did haredim dress influence business wear that much", but that would also be off-topic.

Comment: That is a [smoking/tuxedo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_tie). If you see any film from the 30s or 40s, you will see as the typical formal attire for tich people, without any link to Jewish customs. In fact its WP article references no Jewish influence, either.

Comment: It should be noted that for a long time and even in the current day bank employees had a dress code that was a black/dark suit, white shirt and tie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because in European Christain society, money lending for profit via interest was considered sinful by Christianity and Islam writ large. However, in Christianity at least, it was not sinful to take such a loan, only to offer money for a loan in such a way.  However, in Judaism, no such taboo on being a lender for profit, so it was often that people would borrow money from Jewish lenders and the tropes of the aggressive greedy lender to whom you must plea for more time to get them their money became associate with Jewish people because they were the only group of people who could lend such money in the first place historically in Afro-Eurasian spheres of culture.  If you weren't familiar with how an interest loan worked, the idea of a greedy lender who asks for more money than you borrowed from them will start to develop... and if only one group of people were more predominately lending money... it might be that the poor informed borrower believes this as part of that group of people's culture... and not because anyone who lends money might act like that.

And in Soviet Era propaganda where capitalism was bad and lending money, which is a core driver of capitalism's growth, is also bad, and you have a group of people who are historically associated with money lending... well... you can follow the... well, I wouldn't call it logic because it's flawed as hell... but you get the idea of how we got here.

Comment: that 3rd sentence is the longest I've ever seen.

Comment: One could add that in the late medivial times when this stereotype originated not only where Jews the only ones allowed to lend money, lending money was also one of the very few professions a Jew could legitimately pursue making this association of money lending to Judaism even stronger.

Comment: Downvote because the answer takes at face value the OP's premise that the image represents an Haredic dress. It is way more probable that it is just a tuxedo, which was typical for the rich people of the era.

Comment: @SJuan76 I never commented on the picture, which I can't verify if it's a Jewish person or a period business dress... and quite frankly, don't want to go looking through this kind of propaganda to find.   I was merely discussing the association with Jewish people and banking industry and how it historically formed.   I have no idea if the image is antisemitism or just anti-capitalism.